How to keep the js code in google chrome console running after the page refreshes?
I am working on a page which contains a search button. When I tried to use .click command in console to click the search button to obtain the info I need, the page refreshes and the console ends. Is there a way to run the code after the clicking of the search(refresh button)?
//below is the key part of the code

document.getElementById("ListID").value=Value_1;
document.getElementById("Searchbutton").click();
//after clicking the page refreshes and I am trying to get element on this refreshed page
//the program stops here
setTimeout(func3, 3000);



I tried This: But it didn't work
var oNewWindow = window.open("WebsiteUrl");
oNewWindow.onload = function(){oNewWindow.window.func3();};

What I am trying to get is to
Step1:click the button of search, which will refresh the page
Step2:click another button on the refreshed page by calling func3().
Step3:Repeat step1 and step2 every a few seconds.

Is it a submit button? It's submitting the form, which reloads the page.

Yes. It is a submit button. Is there a way to keep the code from going, such as opening this particular page from another page and use the corresponding functions in this page opened and refreshed?

Make it type="button" and use a JavaScript listener that handles the event without reloading.

Thx, but I cannot edit the coding of the website since I am not the owner. I am just trying to obtain the necessary data downloaded automatically every a few hours.

Then you're stuck with how the website behaves. If clicking the button is supposed to submit the form and refresh, you can't do much about it.
